# Append html fragment as node value in libxmljs

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, libxml-js

I have a libxmljs document in which I would like to append html fragment. For example:

```
var value = '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><p>Soemthing</p></div>';
document.root().node('field', value);
```

But I would like to preserve html structure. Because after generating xml, inside field I get

```
 <field>&lt;div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"&gt;&lt;p&gt;Something&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</field>
```

while I would like to achieve

```
 <field><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><p>Something</p></div></field>
```

I know I can parse htmlFragment but I can't add it afterwards to document. So how to add html fragment? And preserve tags (if they are present)?

Thank you!

Comment: I moved to https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlbuilder which has a raw() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlbuilder which has raw() method and can be used to insert html as well.